# How to pass $http.get() data to trNgGrid table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I understand that this is a basic question, but I cannot find any related tutorial or documents anywhere.

I tried to generate the trNgGrid table using this code:

```
<div><button type="submit" ng-click="requestJSON()">X</button></div>

<div ng-controller="SearchController">
    <table tr-ng-grid='' items="data"></table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
app.controller("SearchController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.requestJSON = function () {
        var httpRequest = $http.get(url, {params: parameters})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // Call table render function
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        })
    };
});
</script>
```

The $scope.data return just fine, but the table won't display at all.
When I copy and past the data to the $scope.data like this:

```
$scope.data = [{"name": "myName", "age": 50}]
```

The table appear as it should.

Please help.

UPDATE:

I asked in the trNgGrid forum in GitHub and finally got the solution.

The problem was that I did not specify the columns in the table. 
When I added the "tr" for each column, the data appeared on the table as it should. So the table code should be like this:

```
<table tr-ng-grid='' items="data">
   <tr>
      <th field-name="name"></th>
      <th field-name="age"></th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated the following:

> **The $scope.data return just fine**, but the table won't display at all. **When I copy and past the data to the $scope.data like this**:
>
> $scope.data = [{"name": "myName", "age": 50}]
>
> **The table appear as it should**.

So, since your manual method of data assignment works, but your httpRequest does not, even though it does return data, *implies that the data your request returns is either not in JSON format, or there is something in the data that is causing the problem*.

Could you show the data that is returned from your httpRequest?

I am using trNgGrid in a project and are successfully displaying data with $http.get and normal $scope.data = data assignment.

Since you stated that you copy and paste the data, then it works, maybe you could try:

```
angular.copy(data, $scope.data)
```

Comment: Hello, I finally got it. I just need to specify the table columns in <tr> then it finally works.

Comment: It is strange that it would still work if you copied the data even though that was the problem.
Anyway, I'm glad you got it right!

Comment: I think it's strange too, but that's how it works. Thanks anyway for helping :)